# Basic Kabbalah books for kids

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mysticism-kabbalah

I'm looking for children's books that teach basic Kabbalah concepts in a simple way. Preferably with illustrations and stories.

EDIT: For all the discussion in the comments, remember that I am asking about a book that teaches BASIC Kabbalah concepts, we are not doing some next level studying here.

Comment: This is the only kids book I know of that teaches a "Kabbalistic concept" (Hashem needs your mitzvot) to children: https://www.amazon.com/Who-Needs-You-Teaching-Childrens/dp/0986277045

Comment: You know there is an opinion that one should not learn Kabbalah before 40 years old, or at the least should have a strong grounding in Torah - I can't see what a child would gain from such a book?

Comment: @Dov there are other opinions

Comment: I know @RabbiKaii that is why I said "there is an opinion". Be that as it may - Why would a person make mystical concepts "kid friendly"?

Comment: @Dov there is a good answer to that but it's not for comments and is off topic to this question.

Comment: I don't think that's a thing.

Comment: @RabbiKaii I would be both amazed and open to hear a "good answer"

Comment: @Dov may I recommend looking into Chabad schooling curriculums, and see what they consider good for children to learn at what age, and how. I am wont to discuss it here because it is an opinion that is highly controversial to many, and I don't want to risk getting called a heretic in public or starting machlokes.

Comment: You could teach your children the stories of Reb Nachman on the basis that they can research the meaning of the stories themselves later in life.

Comment: Feels a bit like "Where can I find good kids books to learn how to build a nuclear power station?"

Comment: @mbloch stop exaggerating

Comment: Considering the level of abstractness on which Kabbalah is, and the degree to which children are unable to comprehend abstract concepts and must "concretize" everything, I think that teaching Kabbalah to a child is exceedingly unwise as it may lead them to literally heretical thoughts. The only recommendation I can give is what @TheGRAPKE recommended as well, to teach them the stories of Rebbe Nachman, which have Kabbalistic concepts deeply embedded in them.

Comment: @setszu No-one in this generation really understands *kabbalah*, so it is probably easier to understand how to build a nuclear power station, which they do.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Ok dude, whats the point of even having Kabbalah if no one "understands"? Don't be nonsense

Comment: @setzu But no-one understands life fully? So you may as well ask, "What's the point of being alive if no-one understands it?"

Comment: @TheGRAPKE False equivalence

Comment: @TheGRAPKE There are many respected contemporary mekubalim. I would say this generation understands kabbalah the way this generation understands gemara, which is to say - the gedolim in their areas are not as great as prior generations, and the laypeople obviously can't come remotely close to the level of the gedolim. But to say that there's no one in this generation who understands kabbalah is completely incorrect.

Comment: @Yehuda You are assuming that a lesser qualitative understanding of *kabbalah* is quantitatively the same as a greater one, which I do not think is correct.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Sorry, I'm not understanding what you mean by a quantitative comparison of qualitative differences.

Answer (score 2):

While it wouldn't work with a toddler, [Tomer Devorah](https://www.sefaria.org/Tomer_Devorah.1.1?lang=bi) by Rabbi Moshe Cordovero, which teaches mussar by teaching G-d's attributes and how to imitate them, would work well with a bright 9-12 year old.

The Ramak was the leading Kabbalist in Safed and Rabbi Chaim Vital's teacher prior to the Arizal's arrival, and by learning this book a child could begin to learn the partsufim, which are a good intro into the world of Sod HaTorah.

Comment: If that answer doesn't work for you, you could also try *The Magic School Bus Visits Meron,* *Bert and Ernie's Adventures in Shar HaGilgulim* or *Cookie Monster, Don't Eat the Pri Eitz Chaim!* But these can be hard to find.

Comment: Also, _Count Dracula Counts To Ten And Not Nine Or Eleven (Sefirot)_

Comment: And who could forget that bedtime classic, *The Seven Kings of Edom and the Seven Dwarves*?

Comment: @יהושעק I reported all of your comments for being condescending

Comment: @setszu not only did I take your question seriously, but I gave you a real answer. The joke behind the playful banter isn't about you, it's about how hard it is to find kosher children's books on pshat Jewish learning, let alone Kabbalah.

Comment: I can't ever resist some playful banter with @יהושעק

Comment: @יהושעק Fine, I'll retract the flags. Its impossible to differentiate in the comments

Comment: Why was my proposed edit rejected

Comment: @setszu if you would like to suggest another book, add it as another answer

Comment: @יהושעק Don't wanna, no need. I just wanted to add that suggestion in here and then mark it as the answer but whatever

Comment: Goldilocks and the Three Chagas: "This one has too much chesed! This one has too much din! This one is _juuuuuust_ right."

Comment: I'd kind of like to see some of these titles in print at this point

Comment: The Princess and the פּ

Comment: The Little Kitvei Ari Says